# Macbook bricked completely

Tags: macos

Was trying to update to the latest version of OS Sierra (10.12.6) and Mac suddenly shut down.

- It gives me question mark on a file when trying to boot.
- Power and then command - opt - R gives nothing, the same question mark.
- Power and then command gives mouse cursor only.

I have Macbook Pro Mid-2010 (A1278)

What to do next?

Comment: Have you tried booting into [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)?   Hold `Cmd-R` while booting until you hear the boot chime.

Comment: Command - R and Command - Opt - R doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried booting from an external drive, either HD or SSD or USB? Hold Option while the Mac is booting.

Comment: I have SSD inserted, but holding option doesn't show it as an available for booting from it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was your MB running on (low) battery when you were attempting to install/upgrade?

Comment: That is the cause of the shutdown, yup. But the soft bricked completely, so that's the real problem here :/

Answer (score 1):

If you have another Mac, boot this one in target disk mode and check the disk / repair it. If you have another bootable OS - you can hold option and try booting another OS.

Lacking those tools, you my have to see if you can test the hardware itself

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

Your model MBP uses Apple Hardware Test. To use this, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start.
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow.
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** The extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Comment: The 'D' button didn't work. Neither did Option + D.. Something is seriously screwed up.

Comment: Did you set up a firmware password?

Comment: @howdytom nope.

Comment: Okay, just to be thorough and as part of our process of elimination, can you connect a USB keyboard and see whether or not you have any joy using startup keyboard shortcuts with that? Also, have you got access to another Mac and/or another bootable drive that we can use for troubleshooting?

Comment: External keyboard doesn't work. Sadly, I don't have another Mac too. I had an OS disc for my Mac, but I've installed SSD in the place of disc reader